# Printing data from JSF Primefaces Datatable page wise

Tags: jsf, printing, primefaces, datatable

I am working with Primefaces Datatable showing paginated results with 100 records per page. I would like to add print functionality to it page wise, for example if user is on 4th page he will be shown records from 301-400, and if he selects for print option only that page/records should get print.

Any idea how it can be achieved. I tried using  but it just displays the visible part of the Datatable not all the (scrolled down) records.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out the option of using Dataexporter with pageOnly tag,

```
<p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="aTable" fileName="audit_list" pageOnly="true"/>
```

Needs to improve on the output more with formatting